# Query two Table, with SUM, GROUP and ORDER on diferent parameters

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables PN and FI.
I need to find all products (id) from a specific year (date) and sum the sold quantity (qtt), BUT each product needs to be returned as 1 line for each Shop (shop). The relation can be made with the emited document (doc).

Table1: "pn" Data sample:

```
id | date | doc | qtt
---|------|-----|-----
x1 | 2017 | d1  |  1
x2 | 2018 | d2  |  2
x1 | 2018 | d3  |  1
x3 | 2018 | d4  |  1
etc...
```

Table2: "fi" Data sample:

```
doc | shop
----|------
d1  |  1
d2  |  1
d3  |  3
d4  |  2
etc...
```

So far, I'm able to find all Products(id) from a specific year(date) and sum all Sold Items (qtt), but I'm not able to search for specific Shop(shop).

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT id, SUM(qtt) AS Qtd
FROM pn
WHERE
   year(date)='2018'
ORDER BY Qtd
```

Result:

```
id | Qtd
---|----
x1 | 10
x2 | 22
x3 | 45
etc...
```

When what I want to get is:

```
id | Qtd | WhareHouse
---|-----|-----------
x1 |   6 |     1
x1 |   4 |     2
x2 |  20 |     1
x2 |   2 |     2
x3 |  35 |     1
x3 |  10 |     2
etc...
```

I have tried with no luck:

```
SELECT 
   pn.id,
   SUM(pn.qtt) AS Qtd,
   pn.date,
   fi.shop
FROM pn
LEFT JOIN fi ON fi.doc = pn.doc
WHERE
   year(pn.date)='2018' AND
GROUP BY fi.shop, pn.date, pn.qtt, pn.id
ORDER BY Qtd
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: update your question and add  a coherent data sample  (not only the result)

Comment: I have edited the post and made the requested changes

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking for help on how to create a Query that returns all Items sold in a specific year, per shop, with corresponding Quantity.

Comment: Since I had to do a complitely new aproche to the isue (company policy), I will not persuie this question. So I would like to delete it since it's produsing more confusion then answers. Thank you for all who helped... special thanks to Forpas.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use qtt in group by otherwise the sum fails

```
SELECT 
   pn.id,
   SUM(pn.qtt) AS Qtd,
   pn.date,
   fi.shop
FROM pn
LEFT JOIN fi ON fi.doc = pn.doc
WHERE  year(pn.date)='2018' 
GROUP BY fi.shop, pn.date,  pn.id
ORDER BY Qtd
```

And you don't need AND with GROUP BY  .. GROUP BY is a different clause respected  where and must not be bond whit where

based on your comment you  should join the sum

```
SELECT 
   t.id,
   t.Qtd,
   t.date,
   fi.shop
FROM (
    select pn.id,
       SUM(pn.qtt) AS Qtd,
       pn.date,
       pn.doc
    from pn 
    group by pn.date,  pn.id, pn.doc 
) t 
LEFT JOIN fi ON fi.doc = pn.doc 
WHERE  year(t.date)='2018' 
ORDER BY t.Qtd
```

Comment: I took your code and changed the WHERE to:..... WHERE year(pn.date)=2018 AND fi.shop = 2 AND pn.id = 'IFPLS933'.... This way I'm checking only 1 product at 1 shop. This specific Item, at that specific year and shop gives me a result of 4571 sold Items, wen it should be only 125... any clue on what is causing this?

Comment: In the attempt of findding why the strange results, I removes the GROUP BY and the ORDER BY, to get all the result for that Item, for the year 2018, at shop 2. For some reason it is returning multiple times the same lines, in a ramdom mather.

Comment: you should add  a coherent data sample .. because based  on your sample the query should worok  .. but we can't  know your real data content ..

Comment: The database has hundreds of thousands of entries, and the presented Tables are a simplefied version of the real ones... since they have douzens of fields. How should I present the samlpe?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to leave the join last.
First get the sums:

```
select p.id, p.Qtd, fi.shop from (
  select 
    pn.id, 
    pn.doc, 
    sum(pn.qtt) / 
    (select count(*) from pn p 
     where p.doc = pn.doc and year(p.date) = year(pn.date) and p.id = pn.id) as Qtd
  from pn
  where year(pn.date) = '2018'
   group by pn.id, pn.doc
) as p inner join fi
on fi.doc = p.doc
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your input. Your code works grate, but I'm getting the same poblem as the other proposals. Each sum of each Item returns huge values. For example, an Item sold 125 times is returning 4571, and another that had only 1 sold returns 78.

Comment: The SUM function will add all values of the column `qtt`. This is the result you get. It is not wrong. Don't you don't want to sum the values? Maybe you should post more sample data and expected results because I suspect that you did not clarify what you need.

Comment: thanks for your effort but I must use Sum. In a row, more then 1 an item can be sold, therefor I must Sum that collum. What is making me pull my hair off, is if I use the 1º piece of code I present in my opening post, for each item I get the total amount it was sold (total of all shops). But as soon as I query the 2º table... all hell brakes loose and the values make no sence anymore.

Comment: Unfortunatly... same result. After a few test querys, I managed to find that the ludicrous values are created because it is adding up the same rows multiple times, on a complitely random mather (althought always giving the same result). Is there a way to remove (or prevent) repeated rows to be added? Maybe comparing the "doc" since it's a unique value for each transaction.

Comment: There is no case of adding the same rows again and again. It's summing the existing rows. So maybe you have duplicate rows?

Comment: For some reason I can no more replicate this "duplicate row" bug... I must have had some error in my query that was causing it. On the other hand I am noticing a diferent behavior. When comparing the "qtt" from each individual "doc", I see that the resulted value are way bigger then the original one. I assume the problem resides in the SUM.

Comment: OK. So the table FI actualy has rows with duplicated "fno". Now the question is how to only have 1 rows for each "fno" of the table FI?

Comment: In my edited code, the summing does not involve the table FI. After the sums are calculated inside table PN, the results are joined to the table FI. So check if there are duplicates inside PN.

Comment: OK... turns out there are duplicates in the PN table... and a lot of them. So back to de same question, how to only load 1 row for each "fno"?

Comment: What is `fno`??

Comment: ho... sorry... "doc". Multiple rows with "doc" on both tables FI and PN.

Comment: No luck... it still returns dupliated rows. During my search I have found the "CROSS APPLY" method. I managed to use it and having no duplicates, but it does not assume each shop. Wen I ask for a specific shop, it returns all the shops, as if they where only one.